# Is there any tiny tips to find counter example string for proving some language is not a CFL?

Tags: formal-languages

When I prove some language is context free, It is too hard to find example string.
Is there any tips? It takes too many time or eventually give up.

Comment: You seem to be asking specifically about applications of the pumping lemma. If so, can you update the question accordingly?

Answer (score -1):

The pumping lemma for CFGs can often be used to show a language is not a CFL.